# Problems instakling android studio sdk

Tags: android, sdk

I have problem getting my android studio to start working.

I have tried severally to download android sdk through android studio settings. However the installation is always incomplete and the process has to start again at everytime I open android studio. I have read almost all answers supplied to similar questions here. Please help.

Comment: Do you get any error message before the installation starts again?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sometimes I get error message for one or two files... But I expect it is those files alone that it suppose to download at other times... But it starts all over again and may encounter error at some other file(s). The last one I did, I did not see any errors but warning of installing in another location. Yet it still wanted to start all over...

Comment: You could try to download a new copy of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) with a bundled SDK. That way, the SDK will be installed in the default location

Comment: OK Thank you. I will try that and let you know if it works.  Though I downloaded another Android studio with over 800mb, yet with the problem still persistence.